# Yii2.0 user management migration failed

Tags: yii2, user-management

Installed Yii 2.0, need to install Yii2.0 User management extension. When I run migrate command it shows the following error.
[image]

I kept *webvimark* folder inside *vendor* folder. If I do anything wrong, please guide me in a right way. 
Also I had tried by importing the *mysql.schema.sql*. it didn't work. Sorry If I had asked immature question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a wrong console app configuration.
See whether there is a 'bootstrap' section inside your config/console.php and it has ['gii'] value. You should remove it.

Comment: I've commented out the gii inside modules in console.php. Still i'm getting "ReflectionException

Class webvimark\modules\UserManagement\components\UserConfig does not exist"

Comment: Please find "bootstrap" key there.

Comment: you are right I 'just commented out the section that assigns bootstrap to gii module. Now it works thanks